# Why do text fields in Excel import as numbers in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova, laravel-excel

I am trying to import Excel-sheets into Laravel Nova, but text fields in Excel get imported as numbers.
It's off course the goal to have the data imported as it is in Excel (text = text and numbers = numbers).

**Excel:**
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQOER.png)

**Result in Laravel Nova:**
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNNIj.png)

*Links go to screenshots, could not show inline images*

I use https://laravel-excel.com/ and https://novapackages.com/packages/anaseqal/nova-import

**ContactsImport.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Contact;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

class ContactsImport implements ToCollection
{

public function collection(Collection $rows)
{
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        Contact::create([
        'first_name' => $row[0],
        'last_name' => $row[1],
        'address' => $row[2],
        'postal_code' => $row[3],
        'city' => $row[4],
        'country' => $row[5],
        'cellphone' => $row[6],
        'email' => $row[7],
        ]);
    }
}
```

}

**ImportContacts.php**

```
namespace App\Nova\Actions;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Anaseqal\NovaImport\Actions\Action;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ActionFields;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use Laravel\Nova\Fields\File;

use App\Imports\ContactsImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class ImportContacts extends Action
{
use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Indicates if this action is only available on the resource detail view.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $onlyOnIndex = true;

/**
 * Get the displayable name of the action.
 *
 * @return string
 */
 public function name() {
    return __('Import Contacts');
 }

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function uriKey() :string
{
    return 'import-contacts';
}

/**
 * Perform the action.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Fields\ActionFields  $fields
 * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Collection  $collections
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $collections)
{
    Excel::import(new ContactsImport, $fields->file);
    return Action::message('The contacts have been imported.');
}

/**
 * Get the fields available on the action.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function fields()
{
    return [
        File::make('File')
            ->rules('required'),
    ];
}
}
```

I have tried searching for something simular for hours, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Try printing the $rows parameter using var_dump on the collections method -> ContactsImport class then see the result from there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are getting the column by its name key by reading this [docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/heading-row.html) then again try `var_dump($rows)` to make sure you are getting the right values from your excel file.